# Locators has 4 matching nodes, how to write xpath in Selenium when we have 4 elements matching?

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath

My code in Selenium:
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/agent-create-profile'][1]")).click();`

It gives error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@href='/agent-create-profile'][1]"}

Selectors hub shows 4 matching elements with the provided xpath:

`````
<a tabindex="0" class="primary-button__PrimaryButton-iSIsNJ cjTSCX abstract-button abstract-button--size-large" href="/agent-create-profile" style="" xpath="2"> Create Profile </a>

<a tabindex="0" class="primary-button__PrimaryButton-iSIsNJ cjTSCX abstract-button abstract-button--size-large" href="/agent-create-profile" style="" xpath="3"> Let's start </a>

<a tabindex="0" class="primary-button__PrimaryButton-iSIsNJ cjTSCX abstract-button abstract-button--size-large" href="/agent-create-profile" style="" xpath="4"> Agent Sign up </a>

<a rel="noopener noreferrer" class="navigation-section__menu-link" href="/agent-create-profile" style="" xpath="4"></a>````


Below is the html code:
````<a tabindex="0" class="primary-button__PrimaryButton-iSIsNJ cjTSCX abstract-button abstract-button--size-large" href="/agent-create-profile" style="" xpath="1">Sign up</a>````
`````

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a set of parentheses, at the start of your xpath and before you hit `[1]`

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@href='/agent-create-profile'])[1]")).click()
```

Another alternative if you want the first element:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Create Profile')]")).click()
```

Comment: I'll add few more options additionally to yours.

Comment: Thanks for replying with above suggestions. I tried your 1st suggestion, it gave me this error: **Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//a[@href='/agent-create-profile'])[1]"}**

Comment: I also tried 2nd suggestion: it wasn't finding matching element with **//a[contains(text(),'Create Profile')]** so i update the same xpath with **driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Sign up')]")).click()** - it find 1 matching node however, it gave me error **no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(text(),'Sign up')]"}**  - Sorry i am completely new to Automation so its difficult for me to debug the error by myself

Comment: as @vitaliis mentioned, we will need to see more of the surrounding HTML code to be able to help.  It's possible there is an iframe or something else there that is blocking the view of these elements

Answer (score 1):

As `xpath` attributes are unique: there is one more option for `xpath` additionally to the existing answer:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@xpath='1']"));
```

And `css` is very similar:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[xpath='1']"));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, i tried your both the suggestions and its giving me error: for 1st answer, the error is *no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@xpath='1']"}* and for 2nd answer, the error is *no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[xpath='1']"}*

Comment: Add outer html code to your question. Maybe there are more that one usch elements with a specified locator. You posted only a part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the method- *partialLinkText*:

```
 driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Create Profile")).click();
```

Or you can select all links as list and iterate through for loop and match with the required link text fetching by getText() method.  IF possible please share the website link.

```
List<WebElement> linkList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(“”));
for(WebElement link : linkList) {
   if (link.getText().contains(“create-profile”)) {
   link.click();
   break;
   }
}
```